# How do I generate a random process value given a set of moments or cumulants?

Tags: python, random, statistics, generator, simulator

How would a create a data set from a **known** set of data moments or cumulants.

Its fairly easy to generate a random number with a known variance and mean.
I would like to get something that lets me submit an array of cumulants (or moments)

```
Example: (ci = cumulent, mi = momemts)
  c1 = m1 or ‘mean’
  c2 = m2 − m1 = σ2 or ‘variance’ (σ = standard deviation)
  c3 = m3 − 3*m1*m2 + 2*m3 or ‘skewness’
  c4 = m4 − 3*m2 − 4*m1*m3 + 12*m1*m2 − 6*m1 or ‘kurtosis'
```

So I would like a function, f, that takes a bunch of ci values and produces a single data point whose array of historical values maintains the specified cumulants.

```
 y(i) = f(c1,c2,c3,..., and optionally [y(i-1), y(i-2), ...])
```

See [Moments, Cumulants and Scaling](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-366-random-walks-and-diffusion-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lec02.pdf)

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag.

Comment: Preferred language is Python